# Invalid identifier error when all listed elements exist

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm doing a basic database assignment on ETL. I'm trying to update a column by referencing three distinct columns in two other tables.

I am getting this error report in SQL Developer:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "DIMTIME"."DAY_TIME": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"`
```

I feel my syntax is bad as all listed elements exist.

Code snippet is:

```
update fact_stage set date_sk = (
  select date_sk from time_stage
  where (time_stage.year_time = dimtime.year_time)
  and (time_stage.month_time = dimtime.month_time)
  and (time_stage.day_time = dimtime.day_time)
);
```

Comment: You sure you have the same column name. Can you post the table schemas

Comment: You aren't joining to anything called `dimtime`? Is that supposed to be the outer `fact_stage`, or more likely a separate look-up table? There is no correlation for the update so it isn't clear what the link is.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to add some ID from time_stage table into date_sk column in fact_stage table. I propose to change sql query to something like

```
update fact_stage set date_sk = (
  select ID -- identifier column in time_stage table
    from time_stage dim join fact_stage fact
    on (dim.year_time = fact.year_time
    and dim.month_time = fact.month_time
    and dim.day_time = fact.day_time)
   -- or instead of ON part use "USING (year_time, month_time, day_time)"
);
```

hope it helps